# Load csv data to table use Hive SQL java error InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm crazy because cannot loading data to table use Hive SQL. Please teach me how fix this bug

To create table in Metadata. I using 2 statement:

1 - Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE db1.test_table_file3(
Col1 INT,Col2 SMALLINT,Col3 SMALLINT)
COMMENT 'test_table_file2'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

2 - Load data to table:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/test/test_test_5.csv' INTO TABLE 
db1.test_table_file3
```

Code below:

```
Connection con = getConnection();
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
Statement loadDataStmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.execute(createTableQuery);
loadDataStmt .execute(loadDataSQL);
closeConnection(con, stmt);
closeConnection(con, loadDataStmt);
```

And result below:

```
Statement 1 create table: Execute successful  
Statement 2 Load data: Execute fail  

java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:296) ~[hive-jdbc-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.datalake.griddatalake.repository.impl.MetadataRepositoryImpl.loadDataIntoTable(MetadataRepositoryImpl.java:404) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.datalake.griddatalake.repository.impl.MetadataRepositoryImpl.createMetadata(MetadataRepositoryImpl.java:49) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.datalake.griddatalake.repository.impl.MetadataRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$10d6b423.invoke(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.datalake.griddatalake.repository.impl.MetadataRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bba82441.createMetadata(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.datalake.griddatalake.service.impl.MetadataServiceImpl.createMetadata(MetadataServiceImpl.java:85) ~[bin/:na]
    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.datalake.griddatalake.controller.MetadataController.createTable(MetadataController.java:117) ~[bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: Did you try to run those commands outside of Java / Spring?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, i run in command is ok

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at the second statements, Below is the explanation for it.

If you have the data in the HDFS then `LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs:/test/test_test_5.csv' INTO TABLE 
db1.test_table_file3` will work.

If you have the file in local you should use LOCAL INPATH `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/test/test_test_5.csv' INTO TABLE 
db1.test_table_file3`

- Mention the namenode before the file path if you are loading the file from HDFS

I would suggest you run the second statement out of the JAVA first and see what error are you getting. People commonly run into the permission issues with the external tables, please note that HIVE user should have access to the HDFS path.

You can refer [this](https://www.dezyre.com/hadoop-tutorial/apache-hive-tutorial-tables) page, explained in a very easy way.

I've noticed another issue from your question, You set the field delimiter as tab '\t' in the table and you are trying to insert a CSV file, not sure if it is the mistake in your question sample or not.

If you ran into some errors please comment with the errors, I would be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks @rob very much about your comment, i tried LOAD DATA INPATH and LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH but it still seem not reason of this error. With DATA or DATA LOCAL error always is InvocationTargetException. It may be my config not allow load data into table in HDFS. Your notices about tab characters is right, it must be comma character.

Comment: @Nguyen.Giang.93 why don’t you try from cmd line if you have access, that will give you a good validation test . Also try changing the table to external table and set the location of the table to the file location and see.

Comment: yes, i test in cmd is ok. Create and load data for table by cmd successful, but execute by java is fail.